# Morphisms that permit arbitrary lifts/extensions.

Tags: category-theory

In any category, monic/epic morphisms are equivalently characterized as the morphisms that map to injective maps under the co-/contravariant Hom-functors. Now I'm interested in the morphisms that map to surjective maps, i.e. that permit extensions/lifts of any morphisms along them. I will call them $\overline{\text{monic}}/\overline{\text{epic}}$ in the following.

I'd like to know if these concepts already have an established name, and if there is some theory around them:
Maybe there is some criterion to determine if some morphism is $\overline{\text{monic}}/\overline{\text{epic}}$ analogous to the usual (co)kernel pair criterion for monic/epic morphisms. Are there other types of $\overline{\text{monic}}/\overline{\text{epic}}$ morphisms, as there are effective/regular/strict/strong/extremal mono- and epimorphisms?

Answer (score 3):

These are precisely the split monos and epis respectively. See [this blog post](https://qchu.wordpress.com/2012/10/01/split-epimorphisms-and-split-monomorphisms/).

Comment: Ah! This is extremely helpful! Thanks!